# footer is npt displaying in joomla

Tags: footer

I am facing a problem for my website, The Footer of my website is not displaying in internet explorer except home page, My website is built in Joomla, although it is displaying fine in all other browsers, kindly help me my website is www.gautampolymers.com

Sandeep Kumar

Answer (score 0):

The footer is visible (and looks good) on Firefox 24, Internet Explorer 9 and 8 (I tested with Windows 7 32-Bit). I also looked at the 'code', there isn't anything (like Javascript accesses or CSS properties) that would hide the footer.

Here's the proof that it works on Internet Explorer 8:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IJSYo.png